# Is it possible to define custom column widths for different screen sizes in Semantic UI?

Tags: semantic-ui

Given a grid with two columns:

```
.ui.grid
  .eight.wide.column
  .eight.wide.column
```

Is it possible to change the first column's width to `four` and the second one to `twelve` if the screen size is, like, mobile?

e.g.

```
|12345678|90123456|
becomes
|1234|567890123456|
on a small, mobile screen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do it with:

```
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="four wide mobile eight wide computer column"></div>
  <div class="twelwe wide mobile eight wide computer column"></div>
</div>
```

It is well described in Semantic-UI [docs](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#device-width).

Comment: does the word order matter?

Comment: yes, the width for specific device should be on the left.

Comment: I've made a [JSFiddle that might be helpful to visualize and play around](https://jsfiddle.net/nbkhope/ve4rsaLh/)